# Use aws copilot with a configuration in a different directory

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-copilot

I want to avoid having a `copilot` directory in the top-level of my project. Is there a way to put it in `.aws/copilot` or similar and then specify it with a command-line flag? The `--help` text is not very illuminating.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, Copilot doesn't support that today. If you'd like to move the `copilot/` directory down in the file structure of your project, you'll have to run your Copilot commands from that level. For pipelines, you'll need to tell the buildspec where to find the pipeline manifest using the

```
build:
  buildspec:
```

field in the manifest.yml file.

Furthermore, the `copilot/` directory contains infrastructure-as-code files that you'd need to commit in a git repo, so you wouldn't want to tuck this directory away in a hidden directory. Hope that helps!